# Will Maven support this application setup?

Tags: maven, testing, ant, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm going to try to phrase this so that it is not an opinion based question. I have been doing some reading into other Maven questions and I do not think this is a duplicate, but if it is, please point me in the right direction.

I am writing a series of WebDriver JUnit tests to test the front end of my institution's web page. The tests are also configurable so as to be used both for regression testing as well as testing new features as they get added to the front end. Essentially module is executed based on the user's selected preferences which will create custom configuration options and custom scripts to execute the tests and then ultimately runs the scripts.

My project is using Maven to manage the dependencies, but was originally using Ant to execute the module and then generate the JUnit report. The question is if Maven would be able execute the project in a similar manner to Ant, as well as be able to generate the JUnit reports (or something equivalent).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a maven-selenium-plugin that can be used to run Selenium tests and maven-failsafe-plugin can be used with it to generate your results.  If you would like to see an example in use you could search for "stests" in [Rice's pom.xml](https://github.com/kuali/rice/blob/b0c55a5553f3872ac35489e192fc4df22c92edaa/pom.xml).

Configuration of properties in your tests can be handled in a variety of ways, I usually make use of System properties and/or property files.  Dynamically configuring which tests to run I haven't found a solution I am happy with.

Comment: I appreciated the link and the feedback. It wasn't quite what I was looking for, but it did get me headed in the right direction.